# What is this called specifically?

Tags: integration, proof-verification, average, means

Imagine you take a radius from the center of the shape, you add up all of the lines as it rotates 360 degrees. The radius is measured from its point of rotation, like (0,0) in Cartesian coordinates,to the point on the perimeter of a shape. Then you take the sum and divide by the intervals of rotation until the intervals become infinitesimal.

Is it called the radius of gyration, or is it a little bit different?

Comment: Sounds to me like something such as the "mean distance of the perimeter from a given point". This assumes the region is star-shaped with respect to the distinguished point.

Comment: So is there anything specific, I couldn't find it on the most common type of web pages. Radius of gyration has to do with the position of an axis, and related to balance and stability of objects. I tried other sites, like this website, other forums, and yes, wikipedia. I look up what you wrote. I appreciate the help.

Comment: That's my term, nothing official or standard.